# GCD Returning Incorrect Results in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, grand-central-dispatch

I have a list of about 8,500 items that load in a UITableView and there should be only about 200 items in which `product.isnewitem` is true. For every 'new' item, an image (newicon.png) is supposed to load indicating that it is a new item; however, when I start scrolling down on the table view, newicon shows up on over 50% of the items. All the items are loaded via Realm.

The check for new items is done in:

```
if product.isnewitem {
        cell.newIconImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "newicon.png")
    }
```

Here is the entire cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentsDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell") as? OrderFormViewCell
        ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ProductCell") as! OrderFormViewCell

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let allProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "basedescription")
    let product = allProducts[indexPath.row]

    cell.productDescriptionLabel.text = product.basedescription

    queue.async {
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let allProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "basedescription")
        let product = allProducts[indexPath.row]

        if product.isnewitem {
            cell.newIconImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "newicon.png")
        }

        if let dirPath = paths.first {
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("T\(product.itemno.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")).png")

            if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
                cell.productImageView.image = image
            }
            else {
                cell.productImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-coming-soon.png")
            }
        }


    }



    return cell
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be issuing asynchronous fetch requests in `cellForRow(at:)`. Cells are reused so by the time the fetch completes, the cell could have been reused for another row. Also make sure explicitly clear the "new" image if the item isn't new.

Comment: @Paulw11 where else should I put the asynchronous call? I need to use some sort of background thread so that the UI doesn't lag and I need access to IndexPath because each product image is unique for each cell. Should it be a synchronous call instead? Lastly, what do you mean by "clearing" the 'new' image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t understand why you use this code

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let allProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "basedescription")
let product = allProducts[indexPath.row]
```

two times in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and one in a queue, I think you must move this code to your `viewController` `viewDidLoad`, or `viewWillAppear` and then use the products from a local array declared on your `viewController`

```
var allProducts : Results<Product>?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    self.allProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "basedescription")
}
```

and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath you should have something like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentsDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell") as? OrderFormViewCell
    ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ProductCell") as! OrderFormViewCell

let product = self.allProducts[indexPath.row]
cell.productDescriptionLabel.text = product.basedescription
if product.isnewitem {
        cell.newIconImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "newicon.png")
    }
else {
        cell.newIconImageView.image = nil
    }

    if let dirPath = paths.first {
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("T\(product.itemno.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")).png")

        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
            cell.productImageView.image = image
        }
        else {
            cell.productImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image-coming-soon.png")
        }
    }

return cell
}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: I have two instances of Realm in this method because Realm requires you to have a new instance in each thread. One Realm instance cannot be used across multiple threads.

Comment: Images need to be loaded on a background thread in a table view because it will significantly affect the UI if loaded on the main thread.

Comment: You can do the image loading process inside the cell, using SDWebImage or any other for load images , but you only need to pass the url to the cell, can you try my answer and can tell me if I am wrong?

Comment: @bkhosh2 finally did you try my answer?

Comment: One problem I see with your answer right off the bat is that I cannot declare ```var allProducts : [Product] = []``` Realm objects return an array, but the type of the allProducts is ```Results<Product>```. When I declare allProducts as var ```allProducts : Results<Product> = []```, I get an error "Contextual type Results<Product> cannot be used with an array literal." I don't know how to declare an empty Realm Results<T> array. The Realm API Reference says that "Results instances cannot be directly instantiated."

Comment: @bkhosh2 I don't work with realm, but my answer idea is what you need to use, please check if you can do using a variable in your viewController and call only one time to `let allProducts = realm.objects(Product.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "basedescription")` anyway, I will install Realm in one test proyect and test, if I have some finding i will post it, regards

Comment: I will try using local variables instead of using one global variable. I'm trying your answer as we speak.

Comment: You answer is pretty good. There is no lag in the UI at all. Please update the line ```var allProducts : [Product] = []``` to ```var allProducts : Results<Product>?```. I'm still having the issue with the 'new' icon loading in cells where it's not supposed to be.

Comment: I've edited your answer, so it has ```var allProducts : Results<Product>?``` and I've fixed the "newicon" image issue where it was being loaded into cells where it's not supposed to be. I added an ```else``` clause to ```if product.isnewitem``` setting ```cell.productImageView.image``` to nil, so the image isn't reused for other cells. Once my edits are approved, I will accept your answer as the best answer. Thank you so much for you effort and help!

Comment: I am glad @bkhosh2, you're welcome, your edit was accepted!!, thanks